# Can not compile LM816 drivers

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

I am trying to install LM 816 driver on my ARM v7 Ubuntu 14.04 machine. I downloaded the drivers from the official website of LM. Then I extracted them and I tried to install them with the install.sh file, but the result is not successful, this is the response I got:

> Realtek Wi-Fi driver Auto installation script
>   Novembor, 21 2011 v1.1.0
>
> #
>
> Decompress the driver source tar ball:
>   rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.24_16705.20160509.tar.gz
>   rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.24_16705.20160509/
>   rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.24_16705.20160509/runwpa
>   rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.24_16705.20160509/wlan0dhcp
>
> .......
>
> rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.24_16705.20160509/platform/platform_ops.h
>   rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.24_16705.20160509
>   Authentication requested [root] for make driver:
>   make ARCH=armv7l CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.1.10-gbe10973-dirty/build >M=/home/ubuntu/LM816_RTL8188EUS_LINUX_v4.3.24_16705.20160512/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.24_16705.20160509  modules
>   make: *** /lib/modules/3.1.10-gbe10973-dirty/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
>   make: *** [modules] Error 2
>
> #
>
> Compile make driver error: 2
>   Please check error Mesg
>
> #

One strange thing is that /lib/modules/3.1.10-gbe10973-dirty/build actually exists, so I don´t know where the problem is.

Any help or suggestion is welcomed.

Thanks in advance,

Ander

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With packaged kernels, `/lib/modules/<kernel-version>/build` is usually a symbolic link to where the necessary source files defining the details of the kernel module interface for this specific kernel version can be found.

You've confirmed that the link exists, but does its target exist? Is it something other than an empty directory?

On Debian/Ubuntu, to build kernel modules against a packaged kernel, you'll normally need to have the `linux-headers-<kernel-version>_<package-version>_<arch>.deb` package installed. That supplies the files that are supposed to be at the end of the `/lib/modules/<kernel-version>/build` symlink.

Run these commands:

```
cd /lib/modules/3.1.10-gbe10973-dirty
ls -ld build
```

and if `build`is a symbolic link, you should see something like this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Jan 25 08:42 build -> /usr/src/linux-headers-3.1.10-gbe10973-dirty/
```

Then your next step is to check whether or not the directory listed on the right side of the `->` arrow exists or not. If it doesn't exist, you probably need to install a package whose name would be `linux-headers-3.1.10-gbe10973-dirty.dpkg` or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for helping @telcoM. How can I confirm that the target exist, I am quite new with linux.

Comment: Edited my answer.